# Quickblox sdk - Authentication token is required error (xamarin.forms)

Tags: authentication, xamarin.forms, chat, access-token, quickblox

I am trying to run **quickblox sample chat application** which I got from following link

https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-dotnet-sdk

Issue here is, **when I run the app, it fails to load base session** and gives error such as **"{"errors":["Token is required"]}"**. I tried to debug it but could not find the root cause of it.

(Example code is using **Quickblox sdk 1.2.2**, which I **tried to upgrade to 1.2.7** as well but in that case also **still that issue remains**)

The method inside sdk uses **service call to api (http://api.quickblox.com/session.json)** for getting session, which I **tried to call by using Postman (google chrome extension)**, in which case I **was able to get the session in response**. Strange it is.

Does anybody know what is wrong with the example?

Update: I tried to manually write http call for getting session. Now in this case, I am no more able to access dialogs and other api calls are also failing(getting forbidden error in almost all sdk api calls after authenticating).

Could anybody tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending complete day found the fix. It was really small issue. Currently sample in github is using `http://api.quickblox.com`as a api end point, change it to `https://api.quickblox.com`and it will start working. Note the 's' in url.

The best way to do this is by using the account settings [API](https://quickblox.com/developers/Overview).

Comment: Well yes it's noticeably a small issue. Could not spot it in a first instance. Thank you for sharing this.